# Dickey-Fuller test

Tags: augmented-dickey-fuller

I performed the Dickey Fuller test and I got the following results:

```
Test statistic:      0.340;
1% critical value:  -3.709;
5% critical value:  -2.983;
10% critical value: -2.623;
MacKinnon approximate p-value for Z(t) = 0.9791.
```

I know it is a one-tailed (left) test, but can anyone confirm me that it's okay to get a **positive** value of the test statistic? In all the examples concerning the DF test I saw I found only negative values of the test statistic...

Comment: What language/system/environment you were using? Could you copy the command you have run into the question?

Comment: I am using Stata and the command I used is the following: dfuller price

Answer (score 0):

Confirmed. You can get a positive df test statistic. It will occur when the estimated beta coefficient of your regression of y on y lagged, is greater than one. In this case the df_stat = (beta-1)/se(beta) > 0, since both the numerator and denominator are positive.